# How to filter grouped routes in laravel based on the requested controller action?

Tags: php, laravel, filter, laravel-routing, cartalyst-sentry

I have a bunch of grouped resource controllers in my *Laravel 4* app like this:

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth'), function() {
    Route::resource('groups', 'GroupController');
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
});
```

The two mentioned above are controllers for managing users and groups implemented with help of *Cartalysts Sentry 2* package.

Now I want a filter which checks the current Sentry user for permission to invoke a controller action. Since filters are wrapped around the group of routes, I cannot know what controller or action the enclosed route is leading to. As far as I know it makes no difference whether the filters are set in `filters.php` or in the BaseController `beforeFilter()` method since the problem is that I do not know anyway how to determine where the route is finally leading to.

Is it possible to determine the controller action which is going to be invoked in the (base)controllers `beforeFilter()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the method `getActionName()` in the `Route` class of *Laravel* which returns the action to be executed (in the form of `UserController@create`, just like a controller route). So I put it to use in a filter where it is checked against the Sentry user permissions. If the user does not have access to, it will render an error view.

routes.php (added the `perm` filter to the grouped rotes):

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'auth|perm'), function() {
```

filters.php:

```
Route::filter('perm', function($route, $request) {
    $user = Sentry::getUser();

    if ($user)
    {
        if ($user->hasAccess($route->getActionName()) == false)
        {
            return Response::view('errors.forbidden', array(), 403);
        }
    }
});
```